# C# compiler doesn't appear to handle version numbers with text correctly for "later"

Tags: c#, nuget

I am getting the following warning when compiling:

```
 warning NU1603: LouisHowe.web depends on DevExpress.Blazor (>= 23.2.1-alpha-23255) but DevExpress.Blazor 23.2.1-alpha-23255 was not found. An approximate best match of DevExpress.Blazor 23.2.2-beta was resolved.
```

It would be reasonable if it did not understand beta > alpha. But shouldn't it understand that 23.2.2 > 23.2.1?

**Update:**

I added NuGet to the tags - sorry about misunderstanding the source of the error.

Also, I do have a DevEx subscription and I am upgrading the version installed to match. But I was wondering why it didn't see that I had did match **>=** 23.2.1

Comment: Note that this isn't the C# compiler, which doesn't know anything about package versioning. It's the NuGet client. That's why the warning starts with "NU" rather than "CS".

Comment: This warning is from NuGet (the `NU` prefix on the warnings), not the C# compiler. `DevExpress.Blazor` doesn't appear to be a package in NuGet.org either. If anything, this looks like a question for the https://github.com/nuget/home repository regarding the version comparisons if there's more data for people to actually look at a feed where the packages are.

Comment: `shouldn't it understand` it does, which is why you get a version *warning*. The warning is saying it didn't find the exact version in the NuGet repository though, which is a more serious matter.

Comment: Where did `DevExpress.Blazor` come from? Is it a private DevExpress Nuget repository? In that case the old alpha version may no longer be available. When NuGet tries to find it or a newer version, it sees there's no matching version at all, it only sees something like it. This is no longer a simple "upgrade" path, so it warns you about it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It comes from nuget.devexpress.com - [How to install the DevExpress.Blazor NuGet package](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t857864/how-to-install-the-devexpress-blazor-nuget-package) But yes, it's private. Guess you need an 
 appropriate DevExpress subscription.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what I don't understand (I updated my question) is the warning says it couldn't find a version >= yet the version I have is > the specified version. I could understand if it wanted an == version. But it wants >=.

Comment: @DavidThielen, the warning didn't say that it couldn't find a version that is >= than requested. It merely mentions that project requests a package with version >= to something, but that exact something does not exist, so it fell back to something else potentially unexpected.

Comment: More details on how dependency resolutions works: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution

Comment: @n0rd Ok, I can see how it can be read that way. I read it as it **couldn't** find a > 23.2.1. But it looks like this is a warning that the version is != but only a warning because it is >. thanks

Comment: If one of you writes this up as an answer, happy to select it.